# Automapper, Mapper Not initialized. Call initialize with proper configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

When I try to submit data into database i get following error:

> {"Success":false,"Error":true,"ErrorType":2,"Message":"System.InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you\u0027re using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.\r\n   at AutoMapper.Mapper.get_Instance()\r\n   at AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Object source, Object destination, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)\r\n   at GoalPear.Web.Areas.PM.Controllers.CompanyController.SaveData(CompanyFormViewModel companyFormViewModel)

Please tell me why i am getting this error as i am not able to figure it out after so much effort.

Here is my controller code

```
public CompanyController() { }
private readonly ICompanyService _companyService;
public CompanyController(ICompanyService companyService) {
    _companyService = companyService;
}
```

This is the SaveData method in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveData(CompanyFormViewModel companyFormViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        int? id = null;
        Company company;
        if (companyFormViewModel.Id == null)
        {
            company = new Company();
        }
        else
        {
            id = (int)companyFormViewModel.Id;
            company = _companyService.GetCompany((int)id);
        }

        company = (Company)Mapper.Map(
            companyFormViewModel, 
            company, 
            typeof(CompanyFormViewModel), 
            typeof(Company));
        CompanyValidator companyValidator = new CompanyValidator();
        ValidationResult validationResult = companyValidator.Validate(company);

        if (validationResult.IsValid) //check for any validation errors
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                _companyService.CreateCompany(company);
            }
            else
            {
                _companyService.Update(company);
            }

            _companyService.SaveCompany();
            return new JsonSuccessResult();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity;
            return new JsonErrorResult(validationResult);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity;
        return new JsonErrorResult(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

My Form view code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Company", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "", @id = "validate", @role = "form" })) { 
@*<form id="validate" method="POST" action="javascript:alert('Form #validate submited');">*@
<div class="head tac">
    <h1>Register Your Company With Us!!!</h1>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="side pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-clean" onclick="clear_form('#validate');" type="button">Clear form</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content controls">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Company Name:</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate[required,maxSize[100]]", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) } })

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">Owner Name:</div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Owner, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate[required,maxSize[60]]", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Owner) } })

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-3">Email:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate[required,maxSize[60]]" ,@type="email", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email) } })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Password:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate[required,maxSize[100]]", @type="password", @id="password", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password) } })


                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Confirm Password:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate[required,equals[password]]", @type = "password", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password) } })

                    </div>
                </div>
        @* I have omitted some code from here for saving your time to read*@  

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">Address:</div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "validate[required,maxSize[60]]", @placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address) } })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="side pull-right">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="$('#validate').validationEngine('hide');">Hide prompts</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   }
```

Here is my Company Model code

```
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Logo { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Owner { get; set; }
public int Size { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public int Phone { get; set; }
public int FaxNo { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
```

This is ViewModel Code

```
public CompanyFormViewModel() { }
public int? Id { get; set; }
[DisplayName(" Company Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Owner")]
public string Owner { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Address")]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

Here is DomainToViewModelMapping Profile

```
cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyFormViewModel>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Name, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Name))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Owner, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Owner))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Email, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Email))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Password, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Password))
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Address, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Address));
```

My viewModeltoDomainMapping Profile

```
cfg.CreateMap<CompanyFormViewModel, Company>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Id, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Id))
    .ForMember(m => m.Name, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Name))
    .ForMember(m => m.Owner, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Owner))
    .ForMember(m => m.Email, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Email))
    .ForMember(m => m.Password, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Password))
    .ForMember(m => m.Address, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Address));
```

Why am I getting this error of mapper not initialized?

Answer (score 11):

Cannot see where you initialize the mapping.

**Solution:**

You can create your mapping profile, for example:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
       CreateMap<Company, CompanyFormViewModel>()
          .ForMember(vm => vm.Id, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Id))
          .ForMember(vm => vm.Name, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Name))
          .ForMember(vm => vm.Owner, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Owner))
          .ForMember(vm => vm.Email, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Email))
          .ForMember(vm => vm.Password, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Password))
          .ForMember(vm => vm.Address, map => map.MapFrom(m => m.Address));
       CreateMap<CompanyFormViewModel, Company>()
          .ForMember(m => m.Id, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Id))
          .ForMember(m => m.Name, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Name))
          .ForMember(m => m.Owner, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Owner))
          .ForMember(m => m.Email, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Email))
          .ForMember(m => m.Password, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Password))
          .ForMember(m => m.Address, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Address)); 

    }
}
```

And then initialize in mapping profile in `Global.asax.cs`

```
    public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
            });

            Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();               
        }
    }
```

**Finally**, don't forget to configure the auto mapper in your `Application_Start()`

```
//Configure Automapper
AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
```

Comment: I acknowledge this is a late answer and I am NEW to Automapper. Just had same error before. Found your post while I was looking for a solution.

Comment: I'm also new and though I'd try it to save me having to write bespoke mapping classes.  If we have to manually configure each property, what is the point in AutoMapper?  Can it not by default map two objects with equal property names?

Comment: AutoMapper is not 100% magic. It doesn't map objects with different names. but it does reduce repeating code at some point, which helps to apply the DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. It's all good; I figured out how to set it up correctly and works as expected

Comment: In the case above, if all property names are the same between the two objects you should be able to do `CreateMap<Company, CompanyFormViewModel>()` and get rid of the `ForMember`s.

Comment: @matcartmill Yes, you're right. Objects have same names don't need ForMember

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using static `Mapper.Map` method, you need to use mapper instance created via configuration, like following:

```
var mapper = cfg.CreateMapper();
var company = (Company)mapper.Map(companyFormViewModel, company, typeof(CompanyFormViewModel), typeof(Company));
```

Preferred way of working with mapper in the latest versions is via `IMapper` interface. If you are using DI container as well, you can bind/register `IMapper` to resolve instance via `config.CreateMapper()` method overload which takes instance factory delegate (i.e. container's instance factory method). If you are not using DI container, you could create for example `MapperFactory` class which will be responsible for the mapper instance creation and its configuration.

Example:

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                //cfg.CreateMap()...
                //cfg.AddProfile()... etc...
            });
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Comment: IMapperConfigurationExpression does not contain the defination for CreateMapper() and no extentsion method CreateMapper accepting first argument of type IMapperConfigurationExpression....

Comment: @mac Since you didn't show it, I supposed that your cfg object type was `MapperConfiguration`. However, you need to instance object of that type, setup your maps and profiles inside it and then use `CreateMapper` method to get mapper instance

Comment: I am still getting this same error after changing the code as you described in the example

Comment: @mac Please refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration), there you can see both approaches for mapper initialization (version I've showed you, and version if you're using static method).

Answer (score 1):

You might be using an older version of AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
Install the latest version of **AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection** (I used v7.0.0)from NuGet and change services.AddAutoMapper( ) to **services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(services))** in Startup.cs