# Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I get error when usinng AutoMaper for netcore 2.1 projet

> Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and **if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance**.
>   *AutoMapper.Mapper.get_Configuration() in Mapper.cs, line 23*

I had configed it

```
 public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
    {
        return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
        });
    }
}
```

File DomainToViewModelMappingProfile.cs

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile{
      public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile(){
             CreateMap<Function, FunctionViewModel>();
             CreateMap<AppUser, AppUserViewModel>();
             CreateMap<AppRole, AppRoleViewModel>();
 }
}
```

File Startup.cs

```
 services.AddSingleton(Mapper.Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<IMapper>(sp => new Mapper(sp.GetRequiredService<AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider>(), sp.GetService));
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks you!

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039968/automapper-mapper-not-initialized-call-initialize-with-proper-configuration

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest you to use the [automapper extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) for microsoft-ioc.

In your configureservice-method (startup-class):

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
```

You don't need to configure the profiles manually then, because the extension will scan for the types in the given assembly or assemblies you pass to it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `.ProjectTo<>()` in any of the calls that you are doing? If yes, try to add the configuration in the parameters:

```
IMapper _mapper; //Inject in constructor

_repository.GetAll().ProjectTo<YourProjection>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Comment: Just what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

## Solution

In `Startup.cs`, you can fix it by replacing

```
services.AddSingleton(Mapper.Configuration);
```

with

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationProvider>(AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings());
```

[Source](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject/issues/83)